# Is there any way to Select All on a PDF on an iPad?

Tags: ipad

If you are viewing a PDF on an iPad, is there any way to select all text? I tried CMD A with the external keyboard after highlighting a word, and it didn’t work.

Comment: I was able to highlight a word and then choose 'select all' from the popup menu items.  That selected all the text.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways on the iPad to select all text inside a PDF:

1. **Touchscreen**:
   Select / highlight one word by long pressing and then tap on `select all` from the options that pop up.
2. **External Trackpad**: 
   Basically, the same approach as with the touchscreen, but instead of long pressing, you have tap with two fingers on the trackpad to select a word.